Creating dashboard with Metronic & Vue & Tailwind
So I want to create a dashboard with metronic vue tailwind. I have 2 zip files, the first is metronic vue 8 and the second is metronic tailwind html 9. first zip is a sample dashboard with vue and bootstrap and its components have bootstrap classes. So I saw this https://keenthemes.com/metronic/tailwind/docs/getting-started/integration/frontend/vue but I don't understand:
How do I use Metronic? Should I add the src folder from the second file to the first file and update the first file? Is it my project file first or do I need to create a new project? I think I should create a new vue project and copy the first file components into it, but these components have bootstrap classes while I want tailwind. Please, anyone who has done this so far, explain to me how it works.

I got their public beta version of 9.0. 0, and I had a lot of import and export bugs in the test (they said it was fixed in 9.0. 3, but I didn't try it). I personally recommend not using metronic tailwind html 9 as your production environment for now.
You can understand that bootstrap is a component and tailwind is a tool
